# How to split the string with deliminator, but also keep the deliminator

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
list1<^0.1>list2<#0.2>list3
```

and I want to split it to an array of

```
list1, <^0.1>, list2, <#0.2>, list3
```

What I am doing is

```
String[] parts = str.split("((?<=<[^#][\\d\\.]+>)|(?=<[^#][\\d\\.]+>))");
```

But it doesn't work.
Did I miss sth? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the lookaround assertions as follows:

```
String s = "list1<^0.1>list2<#0.2>list3";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=>)|(?=<)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[list1, <^0.1>, list2, <#0.2>, list3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split by this regex:

```
(?<=>)|(?=<)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE3jI0/2)

**Code:**

```
String[] toks = "list1<^0.1>list2<#0.2>list3".split( "(?<=>)|(?=<)" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("<%s>%n", tok);
```

Output:

```
<list1>
<<^0.1>>
<list2>
<<#0.2>>
<list3>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just capture what you want  using this pattern

```
(<[^>]*>|[^<>]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/187)